# Datastage : Reading excel from window env. shared folder

Tags: ftp, etl, datastage

I have an Excel file at a shared location on windows environment. I have data stage server on Unix box. I want to read the excel file and load data to a Teradata table. I need help with reading the excel. One option for me is to transfer file to the server location and access it from there but can i read the excel from the shared folder in windows environment?

I tried to use ftp first in datastage. But getting the below error.

```
<FTP_Enterprise_18> Error occurred during initializeFromArgs().
<FTP_Enterprise_18> uri : ftp://server/path/file.xlsx is not valid remote file.
<main_program> Creation of a step finished with status = FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0):

No - it is not possible to read it from a remote location so you will need to tranfer it first (if the shared location is not a SAMBA mount on the Unix maschine).

You can use the "Unstructured data" stage to read the Excel fle one it is on the Unix server.

Comment: I am trying to first transfer using ftp in datastage. But I am getting error

<FTP_Enterprise_18> Error occurred during initializeFromArgs().
<FTP_Enterprise_18> uri : 'ftp://server/path/file.xlsx is not valid remote file.
<main_program> Creation of a step finished with status = FAILED.